# supervisord only runs from root directory

Tags: linux, path, root, supervisord

I am running an AWS Linux AMI.  I installed supervisord using the easy_install supervisor.  No problems with installation.  However the only way I can get any of the supervisor programs to run is to have root privileges in the root directory and I have to type,

```
 # /usr/local/bin/supervisord -v
```

if I do the following,

```
 # cd /usr/local/bin/
 # supervisord -v
```

It does not work.  What going on?

Comment: Does your PATH environment variable contain this path : `/usr/local/bin/`? Check and edit/add in your question the output of `echo $PATH`.

Comment: No, /usr/local/bin/ was not in the PATH.  I added it and the supervisord commands now work in the root directory with out adding the path.  How come I had to add the path to PATH?  When I cd'd to the directory I expected it to work with out the PATH setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your PATH environment variable didn't contain the `/usr/local/bin/` path, so whenever you tried to call the `supervisord -d` from your current directory, it actually tried to refer the program in all the paths mentioned in the PATH variable, except your cd, the /usr/local/bin/.

So, when you added this `/usr/local/bin/` to the `PATH`, now it is able to find the program in the /usr/local/bin/ directory. From there it references the program `supervisord`.

So, the actual search is done only at the locations mentioned in the PATH environment variable.